# Hide Some Text Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have this Dynamic html in my code.

```
  $('#chat-box').html(
                            '<div id="chat-box-msg" style="height:225px;overflow:auto;">' +
                            '<p id="hidepara">Have a question? Let\'s chat!</p><p>Enter your Name & Question in the field\'s below and press ENTER.</p>' +
                            '<p style="margin-top:10px;">Enter Your Name</p><input type="text" id="chat-box-name" style="border:1px solid #0354cb;border-radius: 3px;width: 100%;height:30px;" class="chat-editing" /></div>' +
                            '<div id="chat-box-input"><textarea id="chat-box-textinput" style="width:100%;height:45px;border:1px solid #0354cb;border-radius: 3px;" /></div>'
                        );
```

This what id do to get text

```
var todos = $('#chat-box-msg').text();
```

I was wondering how can i get all html of id `"chat-box-msg"` and hide the text of paragraph having id `"hidepara"`. So in short i want all html of div except the one having id `"hidepara"`,

Dont be too harsh, i am **`newbie`** to jquery.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to exclude the element that you want and just invoke `.text()` function from the filtered collection,

```
var text = $('#chat-box-msg').children(':not("#hidepara")').text();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/95npg/)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
var todos = $('#chat-box-msg').clone().find('#hidepara').remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it using .hide():

```
$('#hidepara').hide();
```

Comment: Yaa i know that,but i want too do it in same line above

Comment: @Richa you want html of it.. or you just need to hide it..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I want all inner text except in hidepara

Comment: Apply `style="display:none;"` to that div

Comment: I am saving all itext in locastorage and displaying it back, so while displaying i need to hide that text having id "hidepara"

Comment: So you have a couple different options - pick one

Answer (score 1):

Just hide element by id

```
$("#hidepara").hide();
```

Comment: This will be much simple.

Comment: @hutchbat YEah that is simple, but does not work in my case i guess

Answer (score 0):

try

use  `.filter()` to filter the selected element

```
var filterData = $("#chat-box-msg").children().filter(function (i, element) {
   return element.id != "hidepara";
});
```